# Kendo Grid ASP.Net Updating wrong row

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui

Sorry, very new here to most front end stuff being used here.  I have a Kendo Grid, displaying nicely.  In my example I have 2 people being displayed in the grid.  When I click on the first one, it makes the ajax call, gets the line items, and displays them in an expanded way perfectly.  However, when I click on the 2nd person (with person 1 still expanded) it makes the ajax call and gets the data, however, it puts the data under Person1, not person 2, overwriting Person 1's data and leaving person 2's data blank.

```
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<PersonRollUp>()
        .Name("gridview-PersonResults")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.PersonName).Width(80);
            columns.Bound(e => e.NumberNew).Width(50);
            columns.Bound(e => e.DollarNew).Width(50);
        })
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("headerstemplate")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetPerson", "Controller").Data("persoinRequestData"))
        ));

        <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="headerstemplate">
         @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
              .Name("tabStrip_detail)
              .SelectedIndex(0)
              .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
              .Items(items =>
              {                               
                  items.Add().Text("Person Details").Content(@<text>
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<PersonVm>()
                     .Name("grid_person")
                     .Columns(columns =>
                     {
                         columns.Bound(o => o.Person).Title("Person Name");
                         columns.Bound(o => o.ShortCode).Title("Loc").Width(80);
                         columns.Bound(o => o.CustFullName).Title("Customer").Width(180);
                     })
                     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Model(model => { model.Id(o => o.Person); })
                        .PageSize(5)
                        .Read(read => read.Action("PersonData", "Dashboard", new{ personName = "#=Person#" }).Data("personRequestData")))
                    .Pageable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .PersistSelection()
                    .ToClientTemplate())</text>);
                  }).ToClientTemplate())
        </script>


    </div>
```

Comment: Im not familiar with .net version, but i suspect it could be rendering all the grids on top of the same one. That can happen because of duplicated ids or something like that. What happens if you remove the name(`.Name("grid_person")`) of the detail grid ? Or better yet, you could concat something to the name like `.Name("grid_person_#=PersonName#")`, not sure if that works tho.

Answer (score 0):

DontVoteMeDown's comment is right - and I do that in my ASP.NET Kendo code when using client detail template grids. You may need to do it for your tabstrip too.

Try updating your tabstrip and grid template code like so:

```
        <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="headerstemplate">
         @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
              .Name("tabStrip_detail#=Person#") //not sure if you'll have access to Person here, but this ID/Name should be unique if multiple templates can be displayed at the same time
              .SelectedIndex(0)
              .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
              .Items(items =>
              {                               
                  items.Add().Text("Person Details").Content(@<text>
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<PersonVm>()
                     .Name("grid_person#=Person#") //Better to use an ID field than name if you have it since the name could have duplicates
                     .Columns(columns =>
                     {
                         columns.Bound(o => o.Person).Title("Person Name");
                         columns.Bound(o => o.ShortCode).Title("Loc").Width(80);
                         columns.Bound(o => o.CustFullName).Title("Customer").Width(180);
                     })
                     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Model(model => { model.Id(o => o.Person); })
                        .PageSize(5)
                        .Read(read => read.Action("PersonData", "Dashboard", new{ personName = "#=Person#" }).Data("personRequestData")))
                    .Pageable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .PersistSelection()
                    .ToClientTemplate())</text>);
                  }).ToClientTemplate())
        </script>
```